Resizing filesystem to increase space in AWS EC2 instance
I created an AWS EC2 instance, and I am using the EC2 instance to maintain a database. I'm currently trying to perform some post-processing on my database (by quering my database in batches), but this doesn't work for me because I get a Postgres error message telling me I am out of space: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.DiskFull) could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp5592.0": No space left on device.
My current filesystem looks like this (output from df -h):
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs          4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs              63G  1.1M   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              25G  512K   25G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1    8.0G  7.4G  615M  93% /
tmpfs              63G  4.0K   63G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p128   10M  1.3M  8.7M  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs              13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1000

I noticed that my /dev/nvme0n1p1 filesystem is mostly in use, but I have lots of space free in both /dev/shm and /tmp. Could my issue be solved by removing space from these filesystems and moving it to /dev/nvme0n1p1? If so, how would I go about doing this?
Thank you!

/dev/shm and /tmp are in-memory file systems. You cannot add them to on-disk volumes.

Got it, thank you. Looks like I need to get more storage

/dev/shm and /tmp are in-memory file systems. You cannot add them to on-disk volumes
